# How to get all users from firebase database that send friend request

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve all the users that have 'request_type: receive' only. How I gonna do that in the android studio? It's for the chat app for request fragment. I want to display in RecyclerView all friend request only.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrH2P.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check out The query below. It can help you.

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend_req").orderByChild("request_type").equalTo("received");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Do your job
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This will not work.... There are two child nodes too in database after `Friend_req`

Comment: Please simplify your database. Just like,
userid
         |
          friend_request
                                -->
                                 pushid
                                           -->
                                            "sender_id",
                                            "timestamp"


You can gain your result by querying in a nested loop. But may be it is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to loop through your `Friend_req` node using `getChildren()` method twice:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Friend_req");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String requestType = ds.child("request_type").getValue(String.class);
                if(requestType.equals("receive")) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Request received!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```